# Is there anyway to execute a jar file with a single word (or phrase) in Terminal?

Tags: java, http, jar, executable-jar

I'm building a server in Java.  I want to setup a single word option that will start and stop the server.  "start" to start the server.  "stop" to stop the server.  I tried to use an executable file that launched the jar, but even using that strategy, I still have to type "./start".  The punctuation is a little ugly.

I wanted something similar to "git".  If you type "git" in Terminal, you are immediately using git's tools.  I'm guessing this is because of a symlink?  If so, how did the symlink for "git" get setup?  I didn't have to manually set it up from what I remember.

Comment: You can create an alias in your `.bashrc` (or possibly somewhere else if you aren't using bash): `alias start="./start"`.  Though this will only work if you are in the same directory as the start script.  You could use the full path if you want to be able to call `start` from anywhere.

Comment: are you passing arguments to the jar or not?

Comment: Yes, I am passing arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to avoid sh or ./ while executing you may use alias, add following at the end in ~/.bashrc file:

```
alias sayhello="./sayhello.sh"
```

And then run the .bashrc file using following command:

```
source .bashrc
```

Finally, you should be able to execute your command using just:

```
sayhello
```

Answer (score 1):

What OS are you working on? In windows you just have to add the location of start.exe to your PATH, then typing "start" in the command prompt will launch the executable and the jar